# How to add icons for Drupal 6 menus?

Tags: routes

I have created some menus with menu block module and placed it in my Drupal 6 site's left sidebar, also used menu icons module to put icon for each menu. But the end result is not satisfying. It demands more padding and text resizing to make it attractive. Can anyone suggest some other technique to add icons for menus in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 4):

Try the css way

```
li.menu-mlid-600 > a {
    background-image: url('../images/my_icon.png');
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
}
```

But there are other ways. Google it. Here is another way:

[How to use images for menu items in Drupal with a simple preprocessing function](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-use-images-menu-items-drupal-simple-preprocessing-function)

Comment: Thanks, followed this approach with little css styling and achieved the result.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used [menu icons](http://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) to achieve this. It may require some theming to show up the way you want, but provides a UI for uploading images per menu item, and integrates with image cache/styles.